# Can't correctly extract information of a file

Tags: python, function

I am trying to extract some data of a file. For that purpose have made a script which reads the file and if some keyword is detected, it starts copying and then, when finds a blank line, it stops copying. I think it is not too bad, but is not working.

The python script i wrote is:

```
def out_to_mop (namefilein, namefileout):
    print namefilein
    filein=open(namefilein, "r")
    fileout=open(namefileout, "w")
    lines = filein.readlines()
    filein.close()

    #look for keyword "CURRENT.." to start copying
    try:
        indexmaxcycle = lines.index("          CURRENT BEST VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION")
        indexmaxcycle += 5 
    except:
        indexmaxcycle = 0

    if indexmaxcycle != 0:
        while lines[indexmaxcycle]!=" \n":
            linediv = lines[indexmaxcycle].split()
            symbol = linediv[0]
            x = float(linediv[1])
            indexmaxcycle += 1
            fileout.write("%s \t %3.8f 1 \n" %(symbol, x))
    else:
        print "structure not found"
        exit()
    fileout.close()
```

This function is supposed to extract info from this file called `file1.out`:

```
          CURRENT BEST VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION =  -1161.249249
  cycles=200 pm6 opt singlet eps=80   charge=-1


  C    -3.87724655 +1   1.30585983 +1   4.53273224 +1
  H    -7.60628859 +1   0.53968618 +1   3.72680573 +1
  O    -4.76978297 +1   4.45409715 +1   1.42608903 +1
  H    -4.66890488 +1   4.47267425 +1   2.41952335 +1
  H    -5.59468165 +1   3.93399792 +1   1.27757138 +1


 **********************
 *                    *
 * JOB ENDED NORMALLY *
 *                    *
 **********************
```

but it prints "structure not found"

Would you help me a bit?

Comment: you better complete the `exception` statement with `except Exception as e:`, `print(e)` . It will display what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to find the beginning of the structure with the code line

```
indexmaxcycle = lines.index("          CURRENT BEST VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION")
```

The documentation for the `index` method says, "Return zero-based index in the list of the first item whose value is x. Raises a ValueError if there is no such item." However, that line you are searching for is not one of the file lines. The actual file line is

```
          CURRENT BEST VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION =  -1161.249249
```

Note the number at the end, which is not in your search string. Therefore, the `index` method raises an exception and you get an `indexmaxcycle` value of zero.

Since you apparently do not know the full contents of the file line in advance, you should loop through the input lines yourself and use the `in` operator to find a line that *contains* your search string. You could also use the `startswith` string method in this way:

```
for j, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith("          CURRENT BEST VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION"):
        indexmaxcycle = j + 5
        break
else:
    indexmaxcycle = 0
```

I dropped the `try..except` structure here, since I see no way an exception could be raised for this code. I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: great, thanks. And how can i look for "CURRENT BEST VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION" only?

Comment: you can split the line by '=' & take 1st element of resulting array.

Comment: @HernanMiraola: I was typing that code just as you were typing your question. Look at the end of my code.

Comment: great. Is `break` analogue to `\n`? cause i should't copy what is after the first blank line

Comment: @HernanMiraola: No, the `break` statement tells Python to stop the `for` loop just after `indexmaxcycle` receives its value. If the `break` statement is never executed that means the desired line was never found so the `else` clause is executed and `indexmaxcycle` is assigned zero. The `break` stops Python from continuing the search when we have found what we want--this speeds up the search. This code has nothing to do with blank lines: it just finds the first line of your structure.

Comment: yes, i understand now. great, i will try it and accept if it works

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an exact match, but the line in the textfile is longer than the pattern you are looking for. Try to search for the beginning of the line instead:

```
pattern = "          CURRENT BEST VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION"
try:
    indexmaxcycle = [i for (i,s) in enumerate(lines) if s.startswith(pattern)][0]
    indexmaxcycle += 5 
etc.
```

`[i for (i,s) in enumerate(lines) if s.startswith(pattern)]` gives you all indices of elements that start with your pattern. If you add the `[0]` you get the first one.

I just noticed you can speed this up if you use generator expressions instead of list comprehensions:

```
pattern = "          CURRENT BEST VALUE OF HEAT OF FORMATION"
try:
    indexmaxcycle = next((i for (i,s) in enumerate(lines) if s.startswith('foo'))) + 5
except:
    etc.
```

This will only search the list until it finds the first match.

Comment: Your code works but searches through the entire file even if the desired line is at or near the beginning of the file. That would make the routine slower for a large input file.

Comment: You are right, thanks. But I already noticed that and added a version that uses generator expressions, that should fix it. Read my answer again ;)

Comment: With Python3, use `next(generator)` instead of `generator.next()`

Comment: @Greg: Thanks, that works for me in my Python 3--unless the search string is not in the file. In that case, the generator is empty, a `StopIteration` exception is raised, and `indexmaxcycle` does not receive any value at all.

Comment: Its inside a `try:` block, so if `StopIteration` is raised the `except` block is executed and `indexmaxcycle` is set to zero. Maybe I should clarify my answer in that regard.